# How to manage memory contraints when analyzing a large number of gene count matrices? I keep running out of RAM with my current pipeline

Tags: r, scrnaseq, seurat

I have several hundred scRNA-seq count matrices, each from a different sample. For my other dataset containg a few dozen samples, I simply merged everything together into one Seurat object, but that won’t work here as far as I can tell. When I try to merge them in the typical way, I get the error:

```
Error in .cbind2Csp(x, y) : 
  Cholmod error 'problem too large' at file ../Core/cholmod_sparse.c, line 89
```

This basically means I ran out of RAM.  I even ran it on the cluster with 1 TB of RAM, and I got the same error.  This is unsurprising, as memory requirements increase exponentially in relation to matrix size.  It seems that this happens when the *merge()* function attempts to convert all the sparse matrices to dense matrices.  Here is my code:

```r
seurat_object_list <- "path/to/matrices" |> list.dirs(recursive = FALSE) |> lapply(\(matrix_folder) {
    matrix_folder |> Seurat::Read10X() |> Seurat::CreateSeuratObject()
})
seurat <- merge(seurat_object_list[[1]], seurat_object_list[2 : length(seurat_object_list)])
```

The Seurat object list is created with no issue, but it always fails on the merge.  I tested this code with a smaller subset of the matrices, and it works just fine.  It seems that I just have too many cells to process in this manner.

At this point, It looks like I have a few options.

1. I could hack together some way to force the matrices into one Seurat object.  But I don't know if that would even be useful, since I would likely keep bumping my head on the same memory contraints whenever I try to do anything with the combined object, such as running *SCTransform()* or *FindMarkers()*.
2. I could divide the samples into groups that are small enough to merge, and process them in the normal way.  But this imposes limitations on the types of comparisons/analyses I could perform.
3. I could keep the matrices separate and analyze them iteratively.  This would solve the memory problems, but I haven't found any info online about anyone analyzing count matrices this way.  I imagine that I would lose a lot of out-of-the-box functionality that comes with the standard single-cell R libraries.  For example, I'm not sure how I would normalize all the gene counts against each other as separate objects.  This option seems like it might require a lot of re-inventing the wheel and a lot of code.

I like option 3 the best, but I'm not sure where to begin.  I am still pretty new to bioninformatics, so I would love to hear some input from those who are more experienced.  How do you deal with memory constraints when dealing with a large number of cells/samples?  Are there any standard ways to deal with this problem?  Is there some tutorial/doc online that I failed to find?  Any advice you could offer is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I get the same error but not running out of memory. I don't think this is a memory problem. It's some internal limitation of dgCMatrix object.

Answer (score 1):

Scarf has been developed to specifically solve this issue. Scarf handles  large-scale scRNA-Seq/scATAC-Seq/CITE-Seq datasets that will otherwise not fit into memory. Unfortunately, this is not available in R yet.

Here is the Github link:
https://github.com/parashardhapola/scarf

Documentation:
https://scarf.readthedocs.io/

Paper:
https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-022-32097-3

Please feel free to create an issue on Github for you use case (if you cant already find a solution in the documentation).

/PD